# WordPress: Interact with Database Query Data and Login

Tags: database

I'm relatively new to Wordpress thats why I'm asking this question. I need something to start in order not to waste a lot of time.

I want to connect a mobile device with the wordpress database. The user creates an account on the WordPress site with his browser. Afterwards the device logs in with username and password and queries new data. 
Is something like that already available? As a plugin or as a manual?

thanks
Tata

Comment: Please be more specific. "Connect mobile device", "with his browser". Sounds just like you want to open a WordPress installation on a mobile device (cellphone) browser and log in.

Answer (score 1):

Connecting a mobile app directly to the database is possible, but ill-advised. WordPress provides great tools for integrating your application with your site using the XML-RPC interface. WordPress has open-source Android and iOS applications, so there's some great source code there to get you started.

- http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API
- http://ios.wordpress.org/development/
- http://android.wordpress.org/development/

In addition, the Jetpack plugin provides a JSON API if you'd prefer to use that.

- http://jetpack.me/support/json-api/